# Linking tables where record in one table has a prefix and other does not

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a report which will allow me to reprint invoices using information from two different tables from Sage 300 accounting/job costing sofware.

I have one table that has an invoice number of "123456" and another table that has an invoice number of "SM123456" referring to the same invoice.  The second tables adds the "SM" so that it knows that the invoices was sourced from a particular module.  Is there any way to link these?

I have tried creating a report with a formula to remove the SM from one of the tables so that it can be linked to a subreport.  However the subreport that I want to print is already using subreports and the second tier subreports are not printing data that is needed.

I am open to any other suggestions.

Thank you,

Comment: It looks like you chose the right way creating the formula. If you give more details, i may try to help you to find out why the "second tier subreports are not printing data". It is probably a issue with the link between the subreports. May you show snapshots of your design and the subreport links?

Comment: Actually, I had to end up calling a crystal report consultant for the software company and they are working on getting it to work by adding a "command" in the database setup through crystal using SQL language.  I am an accountant and not a developer and have not learned SQL, so I am leaving it up to him to help me come up with the solution.  It appears to be working in Crystal Reports, but now to attach it to the Software Report Menu, now that is causing some problems... Now in regards to sub - subreports in Crystal, I have read several different pieces saying sub-sub reports will not work.

Comment: It is slow, but it works.